# Connecting to Serial USB device via WebUSB

Tags: webusb

I have hardware which is connected to the mac or windows via USB Serial Mode. Currently, I have a nodejs application which sends and receive messages to this hardware using "serial" node module.
I am trying to connect to the hardware from WebPage. I used WebUSB serial.js. I am able to see the device and guess it is connecting. But when I try to send/receive the message - it says unable to claim the interface.

I would like to know can I use the WebUSB for USB with serial support?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Have you looked at stuff like https://github.com/monteslu/webusb-serial? Would be great to include some of the things you've tried, and what may or not be working. Code examples etc.

Comment: Hi did you end up working this out? I am looking to connect a scale digital indicator to my app which has serial output R232 but through a serial to usb converter as I have no serial input. Trying to understand if I use the webUSB or webSerial api. Appreciate hearing your experience on this.

Answer (score 5):

The `claimInterface()` call is failing because your operating system has already loaded the USB serial class driver for this device (or perhaps a vendor-specific one such as FTDI). USB interfaces can only be claimed by one thing at a time. The option to change the device firmware so that the interface is no longer recognized by the driver (modify the interface class or product IDs) then you will be able to claim the interface and use code like the Arduino WebUSB library's serial.js that you found.

The other option is to wait for Chrome to finish implementing the [Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/). Status on that can be tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884928).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to run `sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio` in the console.

That way, it unloads the USB from the OS and makes it available for WebUSB to use it and claim the interface.